# ¿Cómo puedo imprimir en formato PDF desde un documento html?

Tags: angularjs, pdf

Quisiera saber si alguien me puede colaborar con lo siguiente:

Necesito imprimir en formato PDF desde un documento html (se esta haciendo para dispositivo móvil y para escritorio). Con `Phonegap` o `cordova` y `ionic`

El que voy a mostrar aquí es por escritorio con electron

Este es el código que estoy probando:

```
$scope.generar_pdf = function(){

           html = $compile(angular.element('#cuerpocorreo'))($scope);
           print_win = new BrowserWindow();
           print_win.loadURL("data:text/html;charset=utf-8," + encodeURI(html[0].innerHTML));


           print_win.webContents.on('did-finish-load', function() {
                print_win.webContents.print(); 
            });
           print_win.on('closed', function() {
                print_win = null;
            });
           $scope.borrar_historial();      
    }
```

Así se tiene que ver:

lo que sale al implementar el código anterior:

De antemano agradezco la ayuda que me puedan dar.

Comment: Puedes usar pdfmake tanto para cliente como para servidor usando bower o npm. Toda la Documentacion esta disponible en http://pdfmake.org/#/gettingstarted Ejemplo de esta libreria: https://jeffleus.github.io/ionic-pdf/www/#/

Answer (score 1):

Una alternativa podría ser utilizar [**mPDF**](http://webscripts.softpedia.com/script/PHP-Clases/mPDF-70851.html), el cual he utilizado.

he [aquí un ejemplo](http://www.binarytides.com/create-pdf-from-html-using-mpdf-in-php/) de como implementarlo usando PHP.

**Update:**

buscando en internet encontré esta pregunta similar en inglés:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818093/how-to-print-html-to-pdf

donde sugieren otras 2 opciones:

- https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf
- http://www.cutepdf.com/

Answer (score 0):

Una buena opción seria usar [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) porque es multi-plataforma y funciona incluso en un dispositivo `Android` como puede ver [aquí](http://www.sitepoint.com/how-to-run-node-js-with-express-on-mobile-devices/)

Luego tienes el paquete [node-html-pdf](/questions/tagged/node-html-pdf) que podrías usar para generar el `PDF`